# Filepicker.io - possible to remove extra dialog for computer only uploads?

Tags: filepicker.io

I've been trying out filepicker.io and found that it is a bit irritating to have to go through two steps if I click on the "Pick File" button and the only source I have set is "COMPUTER".  It still brings up the dialog box and I have to click on "Choose File".

Can the plugin just be smart enough to recognize that it is computer only and bring up the file dialog when a user clicks on "Pick File"?  It already has the div in there to drop files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting idea, we don't actually have this functionality currently, but using the components like filepicker.store and filepicker.makeDropPane, this shouldn't be too hard. Here's a quick sketch of what the code would look like:

```
filepicker.setKey("l5uQ3k7FQ5GoYCHyTdZV");
var pane = document.getElementById("dragdrop");
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function(){
    if (!this.value){return;}
    pane.innerHTML = "Uploading...";

    filepicker.store(this, function(fpfile){
        console.log("Stored", fpfile)                
        pane.innerHTML = "Stored "+fpfile.filename;
    });        
}

pane.style.width = "200px";
pane.style.height = "20px";
pane.style.backgroundColor = "#BBB";                    

filepicker.makeDropPane(pane, {
     onSuccess: function(fpfiles){
        pane.innerHTML = "Stored "+fpfiles[0].url;   
     }
})
```

​
Example at
http://jsfiddle.net/yCDDg/1/

Answer (score 0):

will this approach work on a standard filepicker.io account (no s3) ? the documentation states that `filepicker.store` currently works with s3 buckets only.

Comment: i tried it and it seems to work. multiple file upload seems not possible though with this approach.